# How to instantiate different View from AppDelegate using Storyboard without Tab or Nav Controller?

Tags: ios, controller, view, storyboard

I'm trying to build an app (first one) that has webview. I have used Storyboard and I implemented a WebView that works perfectly. But now it needed to make login using Facebook so I added a new view to Storyboard and I would like to load the root view based on login status. When I mark a view as initial view controller the app works and shows that view but, how could I change that just before show the view?.

I've tried this code and it doesn't work:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];

// Set root view controller and make windows visible
self.window.rootViewController = vc;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I have this error: "2012-12-12 16:40:51.219 MoonBooster[15056:c07] Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'MainStoryboard' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?"

I am not sure where is the identifier for a View take from and I'm thinking about to re-design the app just not to use Storyboards neither segues because I'm not using Nav or Tab View Controllers (we don't need it) so I only can use modal segues.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identifier for the view controller is set in the identity inspector -- it's under the Identity heading, and it's called StoryboardID.

As far as your app structure, I am seeing a lot of posters trying to do something similar to what you're doing, and I don't think it's the right approach. Whatever main view you want at the start of the app (not including splash screens or login screens) should be the root view controller. If you want a login screen, then present that modally from the viewDidAppear method of your main view controller. If you don't want to briefly see the main view while the login screen comes up, then set animated to NO. If the login is successful, then just dismiss the login controller, and you're ready to go. If it fails, then inform the user of that with another screen or alert, and don't dismiss the login controller.

Comment: This does not seem to the right way to to present Login screen.  When you present login screen in ViewDidAppear the current view has already formed and shown (although only for a fraction a second), which does not seem right.

Comment: @ShirishKumar, At the time I wrote this, I didn't see that fleeting glimpse of the current view. Things may have changed since then that make this not the best way any more.